# complex json to csv using python and pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, databricks

i know this problem has been asked many times but still i am not able to convert it to json.

my json file look like this:

```
{
    "itemCostPrices": {
        "Id": 1,
        "costPrices": [{
            "costPrice": 83.56,
            "currencyCode": "GBP",
            "startDateValid": "2010-09-06",
            "endDateValid": "2011-05-01",
            "postCalculatedCostPriceFlag": false,
            "promoCostPriceFlag": true
        }]
    },
    "eventId": null,
    "eventDateTime": null
}
```

Comment: What dis you try? What output did you get? How was it different from the expected output? What do pandas and databricks have to do with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
import json
import pandas as pd

def flatten_dict(d, acc={}):
    for k, v in d.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            flatten_dict(v, acc)
        elif isinstance(v, list):
            for l in v:
                flatten_dict(l, acc)
        else:
            acc[k] = v
    return acc


with open('tmp.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

df = pd.DataFrame([flatten_dict(d, {}) for d in data])
df.to_csv('tmp.csv', index=False)
```

### Code explanation:

#### 1) Read and import your json file into a dictionary:

```
with open('tmp.json') as f:
        data = json.load(f)
```

and you get:

```
[{'eventDateTime': None,
  'eventId': None,
  'itemCostPrices': {'Id': 1,
                     'costPrices': [{'costPrice': 83.56,
                                     'currencyCode': 'GBP',
                                     'endDateValid': '2011-05-01',
                                     'postCalculatedCostPriceFlag': False,
                                     'promoCostPriceFlag': True,
                                     'startDateValid': '2010-09-06'}]}},
 {'eventDateTime': None,
  'eventId': None,
  'itemCostPrices': {'Id': 2,
                     'costPrices': [{'costPrice': 99.56,
                                     'currencyCode': 'EUR',
                                     'endDateValid': '2017-05-01',
                                     'postCalculatedCostPriceFlag': False,
                                     'promoCostPriceFlag': True,
                                     'startDateValid': '2018-09-06'}]}}]
```

#### 2) Flatten the dictionary:

```
flat_data = [flatten_dict(d, {}) for d in data]
```

and you get the following list of flatten dict:

```
[{'Id': 1,
  'costPrice': 83.56,
  'currencyCode': 'GBP',
  'startDateValid': '2010-09-06',
  'endDateValid': '2011-05-01',
  'postCalculatedCostPriceFlag': False,
  'promoCostPriceFlag': True,
  'eventId': None,
  'eventDateTime': None},
 {'Id': 2,
  'costPrice': 99.56,
  'currencyCode': 'EUR',
  'startDateValid': '2018-09-06',
  'endDateValid': '2017-05-01',
  'postCalculatedCostPriceFlag': False,
  'promoCostPriceFlag': True,
  'eventId': None,
  'eventDateTime': None}]
```

#### 3) Load the dictionary in a pandas dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame(flat_data)
```

and you get:

```
   Id  costPrice currencyCode endDateValid eventDateTime eventId  postCalculatedCostPriceFlag  promoCostPriceFlag startDateValid
0   1      83.56          GBP   2011-05-01          None    None                        False                True     2010-09-06
1   2      99.56          EUR   2017-05-01          None    None                        False                True     2018-09-06
```

#### 4) Save your dataframe as csv

```
df.to_csv('tmp.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: i tried the above code you provided in azure databricks but it gives error "'str' object has no attribute 'item's"

Comment: Because the data format is different from the example.  How do you read the data?  With json.load()?  If you print ‘type(data)’ and ‘len(data)’ what do they give you?

Comment: I'm pretty sure your json is badly formatted.  The correct format, as in the example is: ‘[{obj1}, {obj2}, etc ..]’ .  Probably in your file, instead, the square brackets are missing and so ‘{obj1}, {obj2}, etc ...’ is done.  In this case you just need to add the square brackets at the beginning and end of the file

Comment: Thanks. It worked perfectly after adding square brackets

Comment: I'm glad I helped you!  Please vote and mark my answer as best.  Thanks :)